# StripesRuntimeException: Multiple event parameters

Tags: java, stripes

Sorry my poor English.

I’m using Stripes Web Framework and recently I’ve had the following error:

Multiple event parameters [save, managementPreview] are present in this request. Only one event parameter may be specified per request. Otherwise, Stripes would be unable to determine which event to execute.
net.sourceforge.stripes.exception.StripesRuntimeException: Multiple event parameters [save, managementPreview] are present in this request. Only one event parameter may be specified per request. Otherwise, Stripes would be unable to determine which event to execute.

Inside my form I’ve one `<button type=”submit” />` to activate de “managementPreview” event and one `<input type=”submit” />` to activate the “save” event.

Anyone know why Stripes submits two events? It may be a browser problem (as far as I know this doesn’t happen in FF and IE 7 & 8)?

Thanks for your help.

Best regards.

José Perdigão

Comment: I haven't worked with Stripes for a little while, but can't you use the stripes taglib to essentially "bind" a form to a particular action? So you can have 2 forms each bound to a different action

Comment: Could you post the whole form?

Answer (score -2):

Stripes is a server side technology, it is not involved in submitting the HTML form. Apparently you're HTML is incorrect and as a result it’s handled differently by the different browsers.

For creating a correct HTML form with multiple submit buttons, it's important to give each submit button a `name` attribute that refers to the correct Stripes *event name*. Although not mandatory, it's also very convenient to use the Stripes JSP tags for generating correct HTML forms. Here’s some example code:

```
<%@taglib prefix="s" uri="http://stripes.sourceforge.net/stripes.tld" %>
<html>
  <body>
    <s:form beanclass="com.example.MyActionBean">
      <s:submit name="managementPreview” value="Preview" />
      <s:submit name="save" value="Save" />
    </s:form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 

I know how Stripes works and I use Stripes JSP tags.

My doubt was about how the differently browsers versions support the button html tag.

José Perdigão